# Booking last minute accommodation in Ireland

Tags: ireland, northern-ireland

I am planning to visit the west coast of Ireland in a few weeks time to travel along some of the Wild Atlantic Way.  I will be travelling through both the Republic of Ireland, and Northern Ireland.  It will be at the beginning of the UK summer holidays.

I will be travelling by car and staying in B&Bs/hotels etc.  I was hoping to not have to prebook all accommodation, as would prefer to travel at my own pace/don't know how long it will take to get to each place of interest.  What is the likelihood that we will be able to just turn up last minute and get somewhere to stay (we are likely to want to stay in a different place each night)?

Comment: How far are you able/willing to travel after your decision to stop for the night?

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll also be in the [Irish school holidays (see notes below table)](https://publicholidays.ie/school-holidays/)

Answer (score 2):

Generally I think you would be OK, just have to be careful that you just arrive late when there is some event on locally especially at the weekend.  Also around the 12th-13th July you will find it harder to find accommodation where they are holding the 12th (Tandragee this year, but also Belfast, Derry, Lisnaskea, Pomeroy, Coleraine, Larne and Rathfriland) In Donegal around the 12th accommodation can be hard to find as alot of people leave the north over the 12th holidays to go to Donegal.